# Heap property of this array

Tags: java, algorithm

From programming pearls, it is known that `array[1...n]` has heap property if for all  `2<=i<=n  x[i/2]<=x[i]`.

Here is  my code:

import java.math.*;

```
public class Heap
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int x[]=new int[]{12,20,15,29,23,17,22,35,40,26,51,19};
        for (int i=2;i<x.length;i++)
        {   
            if (x[Math.round(i/2)]<=x[i])
            {
                System.out.println("heap");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("not heap");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I used Math.round because 4/2 and 5/2 is same and =2. When I compile this code it shows me at last line that it is not heap. Maybe because the index starts from 1 and we don't pay attention to index 0, yes?

Comment: Oh my god. Write sentences. Form paragraphs. Sorry if you're not a native English speaker.

Comment: this does not make sense. please go through it again slowly and try to reformat and re-word this for the rest of us.

Comment: you should use a `for`-loop instead of `int i=1; while(...) { i++; }`

Comment: No matter what the rest of your code does, it will always print "not heap" at the end. Because you tell it to always print "not heap" after the `while` clause. There is no conditional, see?

Comment: yes english is not my native language i am from georgia

Comment: Your heap property is incorrect. And how many lines would your code print?

Comment: one times sorry  guys  it is technical problem i did not  know what to do no sorry all your answers helped me very much  sorry once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. However, there are a few key notes:

- Each time around the loop, the code will print "heap" or "not heap", as Moron has pointed out.

  - Try starting with a `boolean` variable initialized to `true`
  - Set it to `false` and `break` if the heap condition is not met in an iteration
  - Then check the value of the variable at the end
  - Or, you could just `return false` (or print "not met" and `return`) if the condition is not met in an iteration and `return true` (or print "met") after the loop
- Start at 0 with your loop (btw, java arrays are 0-based, not 1-based); the heap condition applies to all nodes.
- Get rid of that `Math.round` thing. It does absolutely nothing and clutters up your code
- You might extract this into another method